# Overriding colors in React Material UI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Does anyone know how to override colors in Material UI without using JS?
Is there a way to override colors using CSS only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can absolutely do that and there are multiple ways to go about it. Everything is explained in the official documentation [here](https://mui.com/customization/how-to-customize/)

The simplest way is to use the `sx` prop in your component but you can use only css also if you prefer to.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **styled** to override styles. https://mui.com/system/styled/#main-content

```
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import { styled } from '@mui/system';

styled(Box)`
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
`
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { styled } from '@mui/system';

const MyComponent = styled('div')({
  color: 'darkslategray',
  backgroundColor: 'aliceblue',
  padding: 8,
  borderRadius: 4,
});

export default function BasicUsage() {
  return <MyComponent>Styled div</MyComponent>;
}
```